# NetBeans with J2ME can't find the Visual Mobile Designer

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I am new to NetBeans.

And I am trying to create a simple J2ME application,
I have installed NetBeans 7.3 and I installed mobile emulator.
I created a new mobile application project, till now every thing is ok and the project is running, but I can't find the designer tab to drag and drop objects(buttons,textbox ..) on the screen, I have searched all the menus but no results.
any suggestion please.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In netbeans goto Tools menu -> Plugins -> Available Plugins ->Check For newest-> Mobile Visual Designer-> Install.

Internet is required for installing Mobile Visual Designer.